# Simple Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

I am reading in a line from a file and want to split words that are delimited by nonalphanumeric ascii characters or a break statement using re.split but I am having trouble determining how to create the correct pattern. The below code yields:

```
split = re.split(r'(<br>)|(\W+)', 'I code<br>A project.')
split = ['', None, 'I', '', None, 'code', '', None, '<', '', None, 'br',
         '',None, '>', '', None, 'A', '', None, 'project.']
```

I believed I would be able to recognize a break statement or a nonascii character usig the pattern above but clearly it is incorrect. I am having trouble understanding Regex, any help fixing this would be appreciated. I would like it look like the below after split properly:

```
split = ['I', 'code', 'A', 'project']
```

Comment: This is a good tutorial on python re: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the group syntax `()`:

```
>>> re.split(r'<br>|\W+', 'I code<br>A    project.')
['I', 'code', 'A', 'project', '']
```

Comment: Mark, in HTML5 the <br> tag is an empty tag which means that it has no end tag.

Comment: the result i am getting is ['I', 'code', 'A', 'br', 'project', ''] how do i remove the br?

Comment: @ZachGittelman, hmm, the code snippet above is exactly what I get, what version of Python are you using?  That was tested on 2.7.